# Altering blockinfo to include valid nonce and extraNonce's in the miner_tests

Tags: testing, source-code

I currently work on upgrading an old cryptocurrency (fork of an old bitcoin version) to the latest of Bitcoin that includes a lot of tests.

I currently am stuck with making this test succeed: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/2971fd030f6e20ff5279bd86ba18acc5e5ed1ce9/src/test/miner_tests.cpp#L249

I believe this issue is because of the hardcoded data in `blockinfo` (see: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/2971fd030f6e20ff5279bd86ba18acc5e5ed1ce9/src/test/miner_tests.cpp#L54)

How do I get blockinfo to update with the right `nonce` and `extraNonce`?

I tried different things, including trying to increase the `pblock->nNonce` by 1 until I hit the right PoW target, but for some reason `pblock->GetPoWHash()` didn't change after that.

Thanks!